# Avoiding accidentally catching KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit in Python 2.4

Tags: python, python-2.4

In Python scripts, there are many cases where a keyboard interrupt (Ctrl-C) fails to kill the process because of a bare `except` clause somewhere in the code:

```
try:
    foo()
except:
    bar()
```

The standard solution in Python 2.5 or higher is to catch `Exception` rather than using bare `except` clauses:

```
try:
    foo()
except Exception:
    bar()
```

This works because, as of Python 2.5, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` inherit from `BaseException`, not `Exception`. However, some installations are still running Python 2.4. How can this problem be handled in versions prior to Python 2.5?

(I'm going to answer this question myself, but putting it here so people searching for it can find a solution.)

Comment: Don't ask questions just so you can answer them yourself.  SO isn't a wiki of random data; it's answers to questions that people are *actually asking*.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Guess _you_ are wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: Answering your own question if you figure the answer out after asking it is fine.  Asking a question *just so you can answer it* is completely different.

Comment: It's different, but not necessarily against the spirit of the rules. There are many copies of this question on meta; this one has a number of useful opinions, including some mildly to both sides of this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/

Comment: Ultimately, people have different opinions and the site doesn't give an adequately explicit answer anywhere. Given the lack of an explicit ban, and the fact that it is easy to do it, I think it's pretty hopeless to try and stop people. I also personally think it's a fine & useful thing to do.

Comment: The only reason I did this was because of the following line in the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question." I see now that it's controversial, so I guess I'll avoid it unless something really useful comes along.

Comment: Well, I'm glad this was put here because it just helped me out. +1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-352-exceptions-as-new-style-classes), the right way to handle this in Python versions earlier than 2.5 is:

```
try:
    foo()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    raise
except:
    bar()
```

That's very wordy, but at least it's a solution.

Comment: You should probably make the second `except` also `except Exception:`, to avoid catching other exceptions that aren't supposed to be caught.